# I want to print the json object in a tabular form passed using render_template() from python

Tags: python, html, json

Python code is as follows:

```
   @app.route("/send", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def send():
        if request.method == "POST":
            findemail=request.form['email']
            datafound=findlogic(findemail)
            data = jsonify(datafound)
            #return data
            return render_template("testjinja.html", x=data)
```

The data is of the form

```
"629513533": [
        {
          "xyz": "629513533"
        }, 
        {
          "a": "1.00"
        }, 
        {
          "b": "3.00"
        }, 
        {
          "c": "1.00"
        }, 
        {
          "d": "1.00"
        }, 
        {
          "e": "1.00"
        }, 
        {
          "f": "1.00"
        }, 
        {
          "g": "1.00"
        }, 
        {
          "h": "1.00"
        }, 
        {
          "i": "1.00"
        },
```

I have tried testjinja.html as follows:

```
<body>
{% for value in x %}           // I have tried x.iteritems(), x.items() also 
  <li>{{ x[value].xyz }} </li>
{% endfor %}
</body>
```

I get an error that response object is not iterable.  I dont know how to handle json object x in testjinja.html. PLease help

Answer (score 0):

you cannot iterate a string like you want, but it looks like your `data` is a json string, so you could do something like:

```
json_data = json.loads(data)

<body>
{% for value in json_data['629513533'] %}           
  <li>{{ x[value].xyz }} </li>
{% endfor %}
</body>
```

You will have to `import json`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved by creating an array in the py side and passing it through the render to my template.

Example:

```
status = {'summary': data["status"], 'date_applied': data["date_app"], 'message': data["message"], 'location': data["location"], 'title': data["title"]}       
return render.operatingStatus(status)
```